# How can I match <svg><g> in Capybara with xpath

Tags: xpath, svg, capybara

The title pretty much says it. I can't seem to match those tags. I've tried it in an online xpath tester as well.

I saw mention of namespaces so I was hopefully in svg:svg working. Is there more to using namespaces? Something else I'm missing?

```
<div id="kw_demand"> 
  <h2>Kw Demand</h2>  
  <div class="chart">
    <svg width="540" height="145">
      <g transform="translate(40,10)">
        <g class="x axis" transform="translate(0,105)">
          <g style="opacity: 1;" transform="translate(0,0)">
```

Comment: Please post a snippet of xml and an expected input/output

Comment: So `//svg` and `//g` don't work? Also, if your xml has namespaces you have to state so in the xpath, but I don't see any in your snippet

Comment: do you serve it with an xhtml header? Namespaces in xpath work only well if you use xhtml and declare of them correctly, including one for the html

Comment: What XPaths have you tried?

Comment: @JLRishe, I've tried //*[@id='kw_demand']//div[@class='chart']//svg

Comment: @philipp, it is being served with an HTML 5 doctype as it's content on page I am looking to match.

Comment: @JWiley, I don't think there are any namespaces.  And yes, //svg and //g do not work.

Comment: Ok, that XPath _looks_ ok, but is that the exact XML there in your post?  Are there any namespace declarations that could have been stripped out?  Could you paste the full `<html>` tag of the XML in your question, with any additional attributes and namespaces it might have?

Comment: @JLRishe, http://www.xpathtester.com/obj/77f7593d-433c-4611-ad24-8a18cc52ea0c

Comment: If I enter `/html` into that tester, it shows an error about an unterminated `<meta>` element.  And it's right: there are unterminated `<meta>` elements. It's not valid XML.

Comment: @JLRishe Is that the issue though?  Seems odd I'd be able to find anything at all, but searches up to the svg/g tags work fine.

Comment: @JLRishe, I ran fix on it to remove the error: http://www.xpathtester.com/obj/75c4ef6c-9b08-4033-8976-7cc9fa233799 and that seems to allow for //svg.

Comment: If I click `Fix` on that XPath tester and enter your XPath from above (`//*[@id='kw_demand']//div[@class='chart']//svg`), it successfully locates the `svg` node.  I'm not familiar with Capybara, so I'm not sure how it handles non-XML HTML pages. Since there's only one `svg` on the page, perhaps you could try `//*[local-name() = 'svg`]`?